How do I examine an integer in a text
I found some code on from this link How to split text into characters
But \IfInteger function not work
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{coolstr}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{scancount}

   \whiledo{\value{scancount}<9}{%

      \stepcounter{scancount} 

      %\thescancount 

      \def\xx{\substr{abc3defgh}{\thescancount}{1}}

      \IfInteger{\xx}{integer}{not an integer}

   }

\end{document}


welcome! could you say in what sense it doesn't work? what happens and why do you think it is \IfInteger which is the problem? do you get an error? if so, please paste the complete text of the error into your question. do you get unexpected output? please explain what you get and what you expected.

Using \def\xx{<stuff>} doesn't "execute" <stuff> and storing the result in \xx. For example, if you add \ShowCommand\xx after that \definition, you'll see the .log show
> \xx=macro:
->\substr {abc3defgh}{\thescancount }{1}.
<argument> \xx 

... and that's not an integer. You'll need to "execute" (or expand) the string extraction before you test it for being an integer. xstring provides this through \StrMid{<string>}{<start>}{<end>}[<name>]; note the optional ending [<name>]. With this you can do:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{coolstr}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{scancount}
\whiledo{\value{scancount}<9}{%
  \stepcounter{scancount}%
  %\def\xx{\substr{abc3defgh}{\thescancount}{1}}
  \StrMid{abc3defgh}{\thescancount}{\thescancount}[\xx]% Store result in \xx
  \xx~
  \IfInteger{\xx}{integer}{not an integer}\par
}

\end{document}



it must be admitted the error message is singularly uninformative.

nicely explained sir. thank you
